# Run a Windows GUI program over ssh

Tags: windows, mac, remote-desktop, xorg

With `ssh -x` I can run a GUI program over ssh. For example if I have a Linux machine with ssh and x11 enabled, I can run the (X-based) GUI programs (that are physically located on the Linux machine, and actually executing there) and run them from my Mac (i.e., displaying on the Mac, and taking input from the Mac keyboard and mouse).

If I want do the same thing on Windows (start a program on a Windows machine and control it with my Mac), how can I do it?
For now I'm using TeamViewer, but I want to know if there is a solution where I can view only the program on my Mac and not all remote desktop.

(I already tried Citrix.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need some type of remote-login support (not RDP/VNC) on Windows.  Try SSH under Cygwin: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41560/how-to-get-ssh-command-line-access-to-windows-7-using-cygwin/

Then you should be able to ssh from the Mac to the PC, and run programs.

Comment: Do Windows programs (e.g., Notepad, Microsoft Word, etc.) typically support X?

Comment: No, those apps don't support X, AFAIK. You can run X on Windows or Mac OS, but the native apps won't use it.

Answer (score 0):

As addition to the above answer.

Trying to use the ssh-server [this](http://www.putty.org/) and installing and configuring a package from Cygwin for X11 frowarding, [here](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-x11-forwarding)

It seems you need to install some libraries in mac for the ssh-client.

> About X11 for Mac
>
> X11 is no longer included with Mac, but X11 server and client libraries are available from the XQuartz project.
>
> Apple created the XQuartz project as a community effort to further develop and support X11 on Mac. The XQuartz project was originally based on the version of X11 included in Mac OS X v10.5. There have since been multiple releases of XQuartz with fixes, support for new eatures, and additional refinements to the X11 experience. Apple is a contributor to the XQuartz project and has worked to ensure that X11 works as expected with macOS and latest available versions of XQuartz.
>
> X11 server and client libraries for macOS are available from the XQuartz project at www.xquartz.org. Download the latest version available.

[from here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201341)